# How to change the value of a character in a string given its index?

Tags: c, string, indexing, doubly-linked-list

```
void changeChar(NODE **current){
    int i;
    int len;
    int index;
    char *p;
    char final[32];
    char copy[32];
    char usr;
    NODE * temp;
    temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(copy, (*current)->data);
    len = strlen(copy)-1;
    printf("Enter index: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    if(index < 0){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }
    else if(index > len){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Enter character: ");
        scanf("%s", &usr);
        *(copy + index) = usr; //Only works if index == 0??
    }
    strcpy(temp->data, copy);
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = *current;
    (*current)->next = temp;
    *current = (*current)->next;
}
```

Hey, our task is to create a doubly linked list and one of its features is that you have to be able to change the character of the string given the index. Any ideas on how I can accomplish it?

Comment: you want to read the character, not a whole string, so `scanf("%s", &usr);` should be `scanf(" %c", &usr);`

Comment: `index > len` should be `index >= len`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues going on.  Unused variables i, final.  No free for the malloc. 
Since you're only replacing a character, not adding anything, the malloc isn't needed.  Your pointer math (copy + index) may not be incrementing by the size you expect, you really want to be incrementing by NODE size.

A safer alternative is to get rid of temp and do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
      *current = (*current)->next
}
(*current)->data = usr;
```